# How do I prevent my Mac OS X Evernote client (v 1.10.1) from crashing every time I launch it?

Tags: macos, evernote

I sometimes have to battle with the format of bulleted lists inside a note in Evernote. In this case, the native Mac OS X client (v1.10.1) died as I was editing the bulleted list in the note. When I tried to relaunch, it crashed and this continued on every subsequent relaunch. The problem is explained in this [post](http://forum.evernote.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=16636&p=66559&hilit=xml+crash#p66559) (complicated markup crashing the Evernote client when Apple's XML libraries are trying to process it), but how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These instructions were supplied to me the same day I sent a [support inquiry](http://www.evernote.com/about/contact/support/#inquiry) to Evernote tech support

1. From the web, find the problematic note.  Delete it and then empty it from the Trash so that it is permanently removed from your account.  (If you want to keep the contents of this note, you may want to copy and paste it into a word processor first.)
2. Quit Evernote from the elephant icon
   in the menu bar.
3. In the finder, open the "Library"
   folder in your home directory.
    (This is in the directory with your
   name, NOT at the top level of your
   hard drive.)
4. Navigate to "Application Support"
5. Move the "Evernote" folder from that
   location to a different place (like
   the desktop)
6. Start Evernote, provide your
   username and password again if
   needed
7. This will synchronize all of your
   notes from the service and create a
   new local database.

Comment: From Evernote Tech support:
"The problem is occurring fairly deeply within part of OS X that we're using to process HTML documents.  Our Mac team lead has been working to replace all of the broken OS X libraries with separate code.  This is a relatively big project, but we hope to see it finished in the near future.
This problem tends to happen the most when you edit and re-edit some mixed-content notes via the web interface.  Adding and removing content can leave some extra data in the note.  We have only seen this problem from 10-20 different users"